# need to fix right border and should be middle aligned of the content

Tags: html, css

i am looking for below results:

[image]

all is good to go. just need to add border-right to li. 
i tried to add but fail to reduce its height as half of the content. 
how i can achieve the above result using css right-border?? or is there any better way to add border to li as half of the content

below is the html:

```
<div class="link-slider-wrap">
<div class="container">
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li>
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-OnlineAppraisalManagemet"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>Online Appraisal Management</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-LeaveManagement"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>Leave <br> Management</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-Assetsmanagement"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>Asset <br>Movemenet</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-CapexAutomation"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>Capex/Opex <br> Automation</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-SwiftAutomation"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>Swift <br> Automation</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-Compliance"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <h5>Compliance <br> Tracking</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-UserNetworkAddress"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>User Network <br> Resquest</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: my desired result]

Comment: and where is your css

Comment: please paste your css code??

Comment: and jsFiddle with HTML and CSS would be extra nice of you

Comment: @NirpendraPatel I have added image, do you guys have seen?? on my side stack doesn't show. why this strange behavior from stack? am i missing something. and let me post css for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have add some css

```
ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
}
li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 15px;
    position: relative;
}
li::after {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 1px;
}
li.last::after {
    border: 0 none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mjrwjydq/2/

Comment: I am really sorry, I have failed to add-image,  css. but @Lalji Tadhani you rock. without enough information you gave me the right solution in minutes. Thank you all. It will serve me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

@lalji Tadhani Code is correct.

But one more alternate is there if you want to see please check the given below snippet.

You can use image also for border.

[image]

```css
.container{width:1024px;}
.thumbnails{list-style:none;margin:0; padding:0; }
.thumbnails li{margin:0; padding:0 14px 0 16px;width:100px;float:left;text-align:center;background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE5tI.jpg) no-repeat center right; }
.thumbnails li:last-child{background:none;}
h5{margin:0;}
```

```html
<div class="link-slider-wrap">
<div class="container">
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li>
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/social_ios_round-48.png">
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-OnlineAppraisalManagemet"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>Online Appraisal Management</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/social_ios_round-48.png">
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-LeaveManagement"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>Leave <br> Management</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/social_ios_round-48.png">
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-Assetsmanagement"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>Asset <br>Movemenet</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/social_ios_round-48.png">
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-CapexAutomation"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>Capex/Opex <br> Automation</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/social_ios_round-48.png">
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-SwiftAutomation"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>Swift <br> Automation</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/social_ios_round-48.png">
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-Compliance"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <h5>Compliance <br> Tracking</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-social/57/social_ios_round-48.png">
      <div class="link-wraper">
        <span class="icon-clr">
          <span class="icon-UserNetworkAddress"></span>
        </span>

      </div>
      <h5>User Network <br> Resquest</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div style="clear:both">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```